# Define directive inside code to separate code versions

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I am modifying code written by someone else.

The existing code contains algorithms, valid for two situations. The differences are minimal - some data types and sometimes a few extra lines in processing.

The original code sets everything as

```
#define ABC

#ifdef ABC
typedef struct {
    unsigned char a, b, c;
} MyStruct;
#else  
typedef unsigned char MyStruct;
#endif 

#if defined(ABC)
#define SIZE1 3
#else  
#define SIZE1 2
#endif 

typedef struct {
    MyStructtable[SIZE1];
} MyStructA;

void MyMethod(){
   statement1;
   #if defined(ABC)
   staement2;
   #endif
}
```

It works... if the choice is made inside the source code, but i a trying to give the user a option to use either one version or another, and having the hardest time separating the code.

I could create a complete set of files for each version. The problem I have:

since there are complex algorithms, it would make sense to keep the algorithms in a single place... replication code may lead to errors, if a change is made in one version and not other.

I have tried to do something of the type

```
if(option)
{
  #define ABC
} 
else
{
  #undef ABC
}
```

but the debugger skips over and does not see ABC as defined even when going over the "yes" branch.

Is there a way to untangle this code, or do i have to create clear separate paths - duplicating the entire code ?

Comment: Preprocessor directives are handled at compile time. The value of `option` is only known at run time. That idea of yours can't possibly work, as it would violate causality.

Comment: In the example you show, there are not that many common parts. It would be better off as two completely separate, unrelated sets of types and functions. In your real code, try to separate common, reusable parts from variable parts, perhaps with the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like this before. I had a library for which I had no source code, but I did have a header. There was tons of code that used this library, too, way more than I could change myself.

Well I had to code up another library to do the same thing as this other one, but with a different device, driver etc. You get the picture. So at runtime I wanted to substitute my library for theirs, but still have the ability to use the old (had to be backwards-compatible).

So what I did was this: I came up with a few handy macros that could transform text into other definitions. There are 2 header files, and one source file. For example, say I want to substitute FooLibrary for BarLibrary selectable at runtime. In one header file called FooLibrary.h:

```
// don't ask me why, but two levels of indirection is necessary
// to pull off a certain concatenation
// this I got from another question on SO
#define CAT(x, y) x ## y
#define cat(x, y) CAT(x, y)

#ifdef FOO_HIJACK_NAMESPACE

// library init functions
bool ShouldHijack();
void SetHijack(bool yn);

// handy-dandy function-changing macros
#define FOO_FN_NAME(X) cat(X, FOO_HIJACK_NAMESPACE)
#define FOO_FN_NAME_NS(X) FOO_HIJACK_NAMESPACE :: FOO_FN_NAME(X)

#define FOO_DECL(X) FOO_API FOO_FN_NAME(X)
#define FOO_IMPL(X) FOO_API FOO_FN_NAME_NS(X)
#define FOO_CALL(X) (ShouldHijack() ? FOO_FN_NAME_NS(X) : X)

namespace FOO_HIJACK_NAMESPACE {
#else

#define FOO_DECL(X) X
#define FOO_IMPL(X) X
#define FOO_CALL(X) X

#endif // FOO_HIJACK_NAMESPACE
```

Then, inside this namespace wrapper you re-define the function calls like so: say there's a function `bool BarFun(fooargs...)` in your other library, you might redefine it as

```
bool FOO_DECL(BarFun)(fooargs...);
// more FOO_DECL's...
```

in FooLibrary.h. `FOO_API` is your usual `cdecl`-type junk, for me I was doing `#define FOO_API WINAPI` for example. Add similar declarations til the end, and don't forget to close the namespace:

```
#ifdef FOO_HIJACK_NAMESPACE
}
#endif // FOO_HIJACK_NAMESPACE
```

Then, in FooLibrary.cpp, you provide an implementation like so:

```
#include "FooLibrary.h"

// hijack
static bool bShouldHijack = false;
bool ShouldHijack() { return bShouldHijack; }
void SetHijack(bool yn) { bShouldHijack = yn; }

bool FOO_IMPL(BarFun)(fooargs...)
{
    // your implementation here...
}
// more FOO_IMPL's...
```

and so on. Finally, you make one more header file I like to call "FooLibraryHijacked.h":

```
#include "FooLibrary.h"
#define BarFun FOO_CALL(BarFun)
// more #define's...
```

Provide one re-declaration, one re-implementation, and one `#define` for each function. I had some 20 of these functions so I used regex to generate them all for me.

Finally, to use it all, in the target code file, `#include "FooLibraryHijacked.h"` as your last `#include`, or at least after you `#include "BarLibrary.h"`. Then `#define` the macro `FOO_HIJACK_NAMESPACE` as something, say "Foo", and `BarFun` becomes `Foo::BarFunFoo` after the preprocessor gets a hold of it.

Now how to do it with separate type definitions will be interesting. Perhaps you could use opaque pointers if the application code is only passing variables from one function to another.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what this all means, I have just started to create two different libraries but reading this seems obvious that if each defines the same symbols, i will still have conflicts... and there are methods inline defined using #define... i really don't know if this would work

Comment: That's why you `#include "FooLibrary.h"` after you `#include "BarLibrary.h"`. The old declaration is still there, and to avoid conflicts the function names are changed and placed inside another namespace. You only hijack the existing function calls inside one source file at a time.

Comment: This solution is utterly hideous. Put it on your resume and you can get a senior engineering position with any defense contractor in the United States.

Comment: Imagine going back through an insurmountable amount of code though...this simply puts it in the hands of the preprocessor. What's so hideous about it?

Comment: You're using macros all over the place, it's very difficult to figure out what the code is supposed to do, you're inviting macro-related bugs that are notoriously difficult to diagnose, you reimplement *everything* -- and are already using crude code generation to do it for you, with all the maintenance headaches that come with *that*, you appear to be using at least three different mechanisms to handle differing code versions where one would do (and coupling them with epoxy) and you're suggesting that perhaps a fourth would help in this particular case. *Don't leave your name on these files.*

Comment: `FOO_DECL` declares the function, `FOO_IMPL` implements the function, and `FOO_CALL` calls it. They are separated so you can use the exact function names from the original API to make new versions. What's so hard to understand about those?
In my case, all functions **had** to be reimplemented--that was the whole idea.
Also, where the libraries are used, you don't know you're using macros, just like using `GetLongPathName` routes to `GetLongPathNameA` or `GetLongPathNameW` depending on the `_UNICODE_` macro. But you don't _need_ to know. It's a function, a black box, a _separation of concerns_.

Comment: This is very interesting, but hard to follow... I love learning something new so I will keep it as reference but I ended up refactoring the entire code and eliminating the directives... thank you though, I will accept it since it could solve the problem as I asked it :-)

Comment: Glad it could help, sorry it was so hard to follow. Indeed I have definitely taken these comments into consideration...